# Error "cannot find Symbol" when i do gradle build in Java

Tags: java, gradle, xsd

I have several classes from xsd schemas with Russian fields, methods. When building Gradle, I get this error
`error: cannot find symbol protected FNSVipULResponse.СвЮЛ.СвСтатус.СвСтатус свСтатус;`
How can this be solved?

```
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8' tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {     options.encoding = 'UTF-8' }
```

and

```
org.gradle.jvmargs='-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8'
```

It doesn't help

Comment: What is your building environment (OS, locale/language/culture)? Sometimes javac takes source code in local encoding but not in UTF-8, and option for providing source code encoding for javac is '-encoding *'. I am not sure how you can provide javac options to Gradle script, though.

Comment: @MNEMO Windows, Ru, Russian, Ru. Therefore, this encoding is familiar to the OS

Comment: Check your source code file encoding first, and set that to 'javac -encoding <encoding>'

Comment: @MNEMO It didn't help me